# Is “brancher” restricted to plugging in to an outlet?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Can "brancher" be used for both "connecting sth. to an outlet" and "to connect two electronic equipments" ? Examples:

- Je vais repasser, je branche le fer.
- L'électricien branche le compteur sur le réseau électrique.
- J'ai branché l'imprimante sur l'ordinateur.

I checked https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/brancher/10945 , but I am not sure about its definitions and it does not contain examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, *brancher* can be used in all of these cases.

A slightly more formal or technical alternative might be *connecter* in *connecter l'imprimante*

Connecter (*connexer* en ancien français, d'où le *X* de connexion) désigne le fait d'établir une liaison, une jonction, que le lien soit matériel ou pas.

*Brancher* a un sens très proche, mais y ajoute une asymétrie : celle du tronc dont la sève irrigue la branche.

Comment: @jiliagre  "connecter le fer" I'm not sure about.  I think it would have to be "brancher le fer".

Comment: @petitrien Indeed, answer updated.

Comment: Except that "connecter" needs not involve a wire (e.g. wifi), "brancher" does.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Je ne vois pas d'inconvénient à dire *Branche-toi à la wifi* (ou *au wifi*).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and more than the electronic meanings.  It depends on what you want to connect.  Here are some examples in italics after each definition, the first definition being connecting electronics or plugging in to an outlet.

Dans la définition que tu as trouvée, il me semble que tu cherches des exemples de la 1ère définition

> Connecter un appareil à la source d'énergie qui lui permet de fonctionner

mais les autres sens sont aussi importants.

Voici qqs exemples selon Le Robert Micro (1998 quand même, on dirait que moi je suis moins branchée peut-être, 4è sens).

> **1.** Rattacher (un circuit secondaire) à un circuit principal. *Branche la lampe sur la prise.  On leur a branché le téléphone.  Peux-tu brancher l'aspirateur? ,* sur le réseau électrique.  *Cet appareil se branche sur le courant électrique.*

Tes exemples avec un peu de contexte : *Regarde cette chemise, je vais (la) repasser.  Le fer est-il branché (ou bien allumé) ?*

*Connecter l'imprimante câblée ou réseau à l'ordinateur. Une fois connectée, vous pourrez la partager en réseau pour permettre aux autres ordinateurs de la maison d'imprimer dessus même s'ils ne sont pas directement connectés.*  [Manières de connecter une imprimante](https://fr.wikihow.com/connecter-une-imprimante-%C3%A0-un-ordinateur)

Sinon :

> **2. Fig.** Orienter, diriger. *Il a branché la conversation sur un autre sujet.*
>
> **3. Fam.** Mettre au courant, intéresser (qqn). *Est-ce que ce film t'a branché ? Il n'est pas branché (sur le) cinéma.*
>
> **4. Au p. p . adj. Fam.** Dans le coup, dans le vent. *Une discothèque branchée. Il est vachement branché.*

Comment: Ta réponse serait plus facile à lire si c'était dans une seule langue.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista t.b. d'accord.  Je révise.  C'est que la question  cherchait des exemples en langue cible.